# How to use Bpython with GAE remote_api_shell.py?

Tags: google-app-engine, read-eval-print-loop, bpython, dev-appserver

Basically I'm trying to get the Google App Engine `remote_api_shell.py` to look like this:

[image]

Instead of looking like this:

[image]

For some reason this works:

```
$ python /usr/local/bin/remote_api_shell.py banded-advice-96618
```

but this does not work:

```
$ bpython /usr/local/bin/remote_api_shell.py banded-advice-96618
```

I even tried:

```
$ bpython -i /usr/local/bin/remote_api_shell.py banded-advice-96618
```

which is supposed to Drop to bpython shell after running file instead of
exiting, but that didn't work either. I wasn't able to import the proper files from my current location.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "this does not work" mean?

Comment: It basically runs, and then doesn't go into the repl. Kind of weird. That's why I tried the `-i` for interactive so it would go straight into the bpython repl

Answer (score 0):

The remote_api_shell.py script isn't designed for use with bpython, and so this is expected. I suggest you file a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) for this.

Comment: Any way you could help with getting this feature request in front of the decision makers? haha

Comment: Hey @AlexCory, we triage all Public Issues in a timely manner, so no worries. It seems as though triaging has already begun. Cheers!